# what happened there with apply method in python?

Tags: python, pandas

```
In [5]: df1=pd.DataFrame({'Data1':np.random.randint(0,10,5),
'Data2':np.random.randint(10,20,5),
'key1':list('aabba'),
'key2':list('xyyxy')})

In [6]: df1
Out[6]: 
  Data1  Data2 key1 key2
0    8     16    a    x
1    9     19    a    y
2    9     19    b    y
3    6     12    b    x
4    2     17    a    y

In [7]: grouped=df1.groupby(['key1','key2'])
```

here i define a test1 function to see what passed in to this function

```
In [25]:   def test1(t):
    ...:     print (t,"\n")
```

look what i got below, why does the first group print two times ?

```
In [26]: grouped.apply(test1)
    Data1  Data2 key1 key2
0      8     16    a    x 

     Data1  Data2 key1 key2
0      8     16    a    x 

     Data1  Data2 key1 key2
1      9     19    a    y
4      2     17    a    y 

     Data1  Data2 key1 key2
3      6     12    b    x 

    Data1  Data2 key1 key2
2      9     19    b    y
```

Comment: it's just showing the groups

Answer (score 1):

I should have googled it before I posted this question. Now I found the answer.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

In the current implementation apply calls func twice on the first column/row to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path. This can lead to unexpected behavior if func has side effects, as they will take effect twice for the first column/row.

Comment: In the current implementation apply calls func twice on the first column/row to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path. This can lead to unexpected behavior if func has side-effects, as they will take effect twice for the first column/row.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html